# w3wp.exe increse and provoke out put of memory?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, crystal-reports

I am using the Crystal Viewer to display reports in asp.net. I have noticed that every time I view a report the memory usage for the w3wp increases and does not go down after the report is done generating. If I keep running the same report the memory continues to increase. This doesn't seem right. Am I doing something wrong? this is my code:

```
  protected void BtnOuvrirRapport(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
          ReportDocument rptdoc = new ReportDocument();
          examenTableAdapter adapter = new examenTableAdapter();
          DataTable dt = adapter.GetData();
          rptdoc.Load(Server.MapPath("NB_EXAMNE_Report.rpt"));
          rptdoc.SetDataSource(dt);
          rptdoc.RecordSelectionFormula = "{examen.study_rv_date}   in {?fromdate} to  {?todate}";
          Session["rd"] = rptdoc;
          rptdoc.Refresh();
      }


 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", "900");
    ReportDocument rd = (ReportDocument)Session["rd"];
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
    CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
    CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh = true;
    GC.Collect();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

w3wp will be IIS side.

for IIS, the application pool. you can make necessary adjustment.

recycle when hit maximum virtual memory or in minutes.
recycle will create a new w3wp process to handle new web request and the old one once done process it will kill it.

do take note:
manual recycle of application pool will destroy all session. meaning all sessions will become null.
and don't worry about the w3wp. garbage collector will reduce the usage after sometimes.

Comment: thanks Oliver for your answer, i tried to recycle manually from IIS but i got this message no data source.

Comment: @gilas, 1st, check is the w3wp memory consume a major issue to your server? is it impacting the server performance? if non of it then you better stick with the default setting of the IIS application pool.

Comment: when i set value of virtual memory (in pool application) after some showing of reports i get an error (no data)

Comment: @gilas, not sure what kind of value u set in the app pool. when it recycle it will wipe off all sessions. make some twist to your code, it may need not so save the whole report (rptdoc) into a session. the more thing/large data store in a session, ur w3wp will high memory. Session default is 20min, thus after 20min the used memory will only be reused or dropped.

Comment: I use session because the crystal report is not in the same page that the button...:(

Comment: @gilas, your session can only carry the reportname etc info. then at the other page read the session get those reportname etc info and bind at that page.

Comment: i get tired with this issue

Comment: @gilas, change the way you write. it will able to solve your issue.